# ssh -X: GLXBadRenderRequest

Tags: linux, ssh, opengl

I just set up an ssh server on my netbook, running Linux Mint 15. I have a program called fluxus installed on my netbook, which is basically a graphical rendering of scheme/racket code.

I ssh'ed into my netbook using another computer running Ubuntu 13.04, and I got this error:

```
laura@bbydhyonchord:~$ ssh -X laura@drukqs
laura@drukqs's password: 
Welcome to Linux Mint 15 Olivia (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-27-generic i686)

Welcome to Linux Mint
 * Documentation:  http://www.linuxmint.com

laura@drukqs ~/fluxus $ fluxus
Welcome to fluxus.
Type (help) for info.
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadRenderRequest
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  1 (X_GLXRender)
  Serial number of failed request:  61
  Current serial number in output stream:  62
laura@drukqs ~/fluxus $ ./fluxus
Welcome to fluxus.
Type (help) for info.
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadRenderRequest
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  1 (X_GLXRender)
  Serial number of failed request:  61
  Current serial number in output stream:  62
```

Could this be an ssh problem, an OpenGL problem, video drivers?

Comment: Does `fluxus` work OK on the remote machine? Does it display properly when run from you local machine? Does it work better if you `ssh -Y` instead of `ssh -X`? Does it work if your run `xhost +` on the local machine before running fluxus?

Comment: It works on the remote machine, same problem with ssh -Y, and access control was already disabled...a GUI screen does show up for a fraction of a second before closing with the error, fwiw.

Comment: Ah, it's worth a lot. That means you know it is not an X authentication error. I assume other GUI programs run OK on the remote (and display on your local)? Also, just to clarify, fluxus works on both the remote and the local machine? I would guess that the ssh connection is not fast enough for the 3D rendering you are trying to do.

Comment: OK, please post your graphics card details (remote and local) and try running `glxgears` on your local machine and post the output here.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely an OpenGL and/or Mesa library problem. Try installing this package on Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

If the library is installed you should be able to run the command `glxinfo`. Additionally you can double check that things are working correctly by running the `glxdemo` both locally and via the `ssh` connection.

There are other apps included that you can try too:

- glxheads
- glxgears

These should all run smoothly, if they don't, then your Ubuntu system's video hardware and drivers aren't up to displaying this particular application. If it's an ATI and/or NVidia graphics card then you'll likely need to use the native drivers for the card!

If they run choppy like this, then you're not optimally configured:

```
$ glxgears 
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
25 frames in 5.0 seconds =  4.971 FPS
24 frames in 5.2 seconds =  4.626 FPS
25 frames in 5.1 seconds =  4.912 FPS
23 frames in 5.2 seconds =  4.398 FPS
23 frames in 5.0 seconds =  4.569 FPS
24 frames in 5.2 seconds =  4.599 FPS
23 frames in 5.0 seconds =  4.566 FPS
24 frames in 5.2 seconds =  4.608 FPS
23 frames in 5.1 seconds =  4.533 FPS
23 frames in 5.1 seconds =  4.495 FPS
24 frames in 5.2 seconds =  4.608 FPS
23 frames in 5.1 seconds =  4.480 FPS
24 frames in 5.1 seconds =  4.671 FPS
24 frames in 5.2 seconds =  4.619 FPS
23 frames in 5.1 seconds =  4.509 FPS
24 frames in 5.2 seconds =  4.646 FPS
24 frames in 5.2 seconds =  4.613 FPS
24 frames in 5.2 seconds =  4.646 FPS
24 frames in 5.1 seconds =  4.678 FPS
24 frames in 5.2 seconds =  4.635 FPS
23 frames in 5.0 seconds =  4.555 FPS
...
...
24 frames in 5.1 seconds =  4.727 FPS
24 frames in 5.0 seconds =  4.794 FPS
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server "localhost:10.0"
      after 3488 requests (3488 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```